# monthtodate minus 1 day

Tags: formula, crystal-reports-2008

I'm using the following formula to extract the month to date data in a report:

```
If {vw_Scale_Tickets.SiteBillingGroup} = "Waste Owners" and 
   {vw_Scale_Tickets.TicketDate}= monthtodate then 
       {vw_Scale_Tickets.TicketNetWeight}/2000 else 0
```

The code works fine, but I need the month to date information *not* to include the current day the report is run.

I tried `... = monthtodate - 1`, but it doesn't work.

I can re-code, but I'm curious if there is a way to continue to use the `monthtodate` syntax.

There are many formulas in the report and I'm trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add in your if clause

```
AND {vw_Scale_Tickets.TicketDate} <> CurrentDate
```